# codec can't decode byte 0x89 Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, png

So I'm trying to integrate the raw image into my insert statement in Python

```
with open(filename, "rb") as imageFile:
    im = open(filename, encoding="UTF-8")

    state = "INSERT INTO T_DOCUMENT (BINCONTENT, DOCNAME) VALUES (" + im.read() + ", '.png')"
    repo.Execute(state)
```

This is just my current code. I tried various things I found (also searched on stack overflow) but I can't seem to find it. I need to insert like the raw png file into the DB.
I'm using Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

In the second line, you're trying to reopen a file you already have opened (as the variable `imageFile`), and you're trying to read it as UTF-8-encoded text instead of as a binary. Not surprisingly, the decoder hit a byte in your image that isn't valid UTF-8.

I think what you want is to delete the second line and then use `imageFile.read()` instead of `im.read()`. However, without knowing exactly what kind of database interface you're using, I would bet that this still won't work, because you're appending a `bytes` object to a `str`, and constructing a SQL statement with string operations is [usually a bad idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use your interface's facility for [parametric statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. It's an Oracle DB. However I'm using an API of the program and the execute is not not like the classic cursor.execute which you can enter multiple parameters so you have to just enter one statement... If this won't work I will have to connect separately for this operation

Comment: @Manuel There must be some recommended practice to avoid SQL injection attacks, even if parametric statements aren't supported. Perhaps there's a function to render a given value in Oracle SQL syntax, for example.